# How to hide loader started on parent body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup

I am showing a popup in an iframe. In parent body I showed loader as

```
$('body').loader('show');
```

How can I hide this loader by accessing parent body, I know parent body can be accessed as

```
window.parent.document.body
```

This works for me:

```
$('.loading-mask', window.parent.document.body).css('display', 'none');
```

But I need to know what is the best way to do this ?

Tried:

```
$('body', window.parent.document).loader('hide');
window.parent.$.body.loader('hide');
```

but no luck, any idea ??

Comment: The method you're using is fine. The only improvement I'd suggest is to use `hide()` instead of `css()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thanks a lot, have used your suggestion. I was just seeking the best way to hide loader from parent body.